# How to change material properties of model loaded with OBJ + MTLLoader?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have successfully loaded an .obj model with the correct materials mapped onto the model thanks to its companion .mtl file. But currently the loaded model is very dark so changing the emissive color to white would be a good idea but I can't find a way to do it. I have this:

```
MTLLoader.setTexturePath( '../models/' );
MTLLoader.setPath( '../models/' );
var url = "model.mtl";
MTLLoader.load( url, function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();
    OBJLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    OBJLoader.setPath( '../models/' );
    OBJLoader.load( 'model.obj', function ( object ) {

        scene.add( object );

    });
});
```

I've tried doing this:

```
object.traverse (function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              child.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({emissive: 'white'});
            }
         });
```

Which works on its own creating a emissive material but disregards my .mtl file. Is there a way I can combine both of them? I can't seem to find anything related to this anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the material. What you want to do is modifying it by only changing the emissive value:

```
object.traverse (function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
          child.material.emissive.setHex( 0xFFFFFF );
        }
     });
```

Comment: I get the error "Cannot read property 'setHex' of undefined", do you know what went wrong?

Comment: Then its a `THREE.Mesh` without a material. Add another check for the meshs material: `if ( child.material instanceof THREE.Material ) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: Thanks, I also edited the MTLLoader manually to my preferences which worked as well in this case.